# Non-virtual function in the base class with same name but different signature not found

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

```
struct A
{
    void foo() { cout << "a:foo(void)" << endl; }
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
};

struct B : public A
{
    virtual void foo(int) override { cout << "b:foo(int)" << endl; }
};


int main()
{
    B x;
    x.foo();
}
```

So, here's the code sample. In the main, I would expect to have the non virtual `foo()` to be called for `x.foo()`, but this is not the case, compiler gives the following error:

```
    x.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    x.cpp:20:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::foo()’
        20 |     x.foo();
           |           ^
    x.cpp:12:18: note: candidate: ‘virtual void B::foo(int)’
        12 |     virtual void foo(int x) override { cout << "b:foo(int)" << endl; }
           |                  ^~~
    x.cpp:12:18: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

It seems like compiler is not able to find the foo() function from A. Adding `virtual` to the `A::void foo(void)` function does not help (same error). Can anyone explain what is going on and why is this not working ?

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need `virtual` in `B`. It'll be `virtual` automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a function in a derived class, the overload set with the same name as that function in the base class gets hidden in the derived class. So the compiler only finds the `foo` taking an `int` in the derived class, which causes an error.

If you want to bring the overload set of `foo` from the base class into the derived class, you can use a `using` declaration like this:

```
struct B : public A
{
    using A::foo;
    // ...
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oeY838).

Comment: Overriding doesn’t matter here. Defining **any** name (member function, member data, typedef name) in a derived class hides **everything** with that name in the base class. Name lookup stops when the name is found.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, absolutely right. Fixed, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

replace :

```
x.foo();
```

with :

```
x.A::foo();
```

and it will works . that's happen because you confuse the compiler by make one of the method virtual and the other non virtual , you need to make them two virtual or change the name of the second method

Comment: The compiler isn’t confused. Name lookup stops when the name is found, so the compiler doesn’t look for `foo` in the base class. Making them both virtual won’t change this.

Comment: @peteBecker that's what i mean : https://onlinegdb.com/ryyLxX5vv